# What is allocated in memory when arrays aren't fully filled? ( C )

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I created an array like this: `int thisArray[20] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`

Then I created a variable to store the size of the array:

```
int this = sizeof(thisArray);
```

When I tell the program to print the value of `this` it shows me 80 instead of 20.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The size is 20 ints, because you said so. And an int is 4 bytes and 4*20=80.

Comment: `sizeof` That's the size in bytes, not the number of elements

Comment: An `int` is 4 bytes wide so 20 `int`s is 80 bytes.

Comment: To know the number elements of an array use `sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

When you give an initializer without explicitly initializing everything, anything not explicitly set will be set to 0.

Section 6.7.9 p 21 of the C11 standard:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
>   are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
>   string literal used to initialize an array of known size  than  there 
>   are  elements  in  the  array,  *the  remainder  of  the  aggregate 
>   shall  be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static
>   storage duration.*

And the rules for static storage duration referenced here are in 6.7.9 p 10

> If  an  object  that  has  automatic  storage  duration  is  not 
>   initialized  explicitly,  its  value  is indeterminate.   If  an 
>   object  that  has  static  or  thread  storage  duration  is  not 
>   initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer; —  if
>     it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned)
>     zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized
>     (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is
>     initialized to zero bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named
>     member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any
>     padding is initialized to zero bits;

As for why you get `80` instead of `20` for `sizeof` because an int is presumably 4 bytes on your system, so 20 * 4 = 80 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything *wrong*, you just have to reset your expectations.

`sizeof` evaluates to the size of the array *in bytes*, not the number of elements.  You declared `thisArray` to have 20 elements of type `int`, and it's a good bet `sizeof (int)` on your system is 4.  Thus, the result of `sizeof` on this object will be 80.

There's a trick to get the number of elements in an array:

```
size_t elements = sizeof myArray / sizeof myArray[0];
```

That is, you take the total size of the array (80 bytes) and divide by the size of a single element (4 in this case).  Note that this trick will *only* work if the operand of the first `sizeof` is an *array* type (that is, declared as `T arr[N]`).  If it's a *pointer* type, then this won't work - you'll be dividing the size of the pointer object by the size of an array element.